# How to put 2 comparisons in one if statment?

Tags: java, if-statement

Iwanna know how to put a two comparisons in the same if-statement, like if 5<6 and <7 too.

Please answer me.
Thanx..

Comment: if (5 < 6 && 5 < 7). Seriously, read an introductory Java book. This is the kind of question that you should be able to answer by yourself.

Comment: Some questions should be auto deleted.

Comment: Okay, i'm gonna delete it, thanx anyway for answering and i want to say that i'm new at java (:

Comment: BTW, you don't need to check `if 5<6`, I can guarantee it'll be always true :D

Comment: @AdoreKidrauhl You don't have to delete it. But you have to do a minimal search before you post such questions. If you write the title on *google* I'm sure you'll get over 1000 answers.

Comment: I remember times when it was specifically OK to ask beginner questions. But maybe that was a different Stack Overflow. Or maybe the rules have changed again.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the logical "and" operator `&&`:

```
if (x < 6 && y < 7) {
   ...
}
```

Of course checking that the same value is less than both 6 and 7 is redundant, since anything that's less than six is guaranteed to be less than seven. That's why I've used two different variables in my example.

Answer (score 2):

```
if((5<6) && (5<7)){
  // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if( 5<6 && 5 <7){
..........

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
if ( (5 < 6) && (5 < 7) ){
    doSomething()
}
```

Seriously, all you have to do is type "AND operator java" into google and you'll find tons of information on java syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (5 < 6 && 5 < 7) {
}
```

Parentheses like this (5 < 6) && (5 < 7) aren't necessary. However you should add them for easy reading